# How to get rid of repeating values in List of Java Bean objects

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, javabeans

I am developing a web based system using Java and database queries.

I have a bean class representing the rows in one of tables in the database - RoadList.

Here is the structure of the class:

```
public class RoadList 
{
  private String roadListNumber;
  private DateTime date;
  private String vehicleId;
  private Driver driver;
  private int startKm;
  private int probegKm;
  private int endKm;
  private int palenProbegKm;
  private DateTime startTime;
  private DateTime endTime;
  private BigDecimal driverWorkTime;
  private BigDecimal workTimeObekt;
  private BigDecimal chasoveRazhod;
  private int mcm;
  private BigDecimal tkm;
  private BigDecimal fualNalichnost;
  private int fuelFill;
  private int fuelGps;
  private int fuelOstatak;
  private String zabelejka;

  private List<CargoPlace> cargoPlaces;
}
```

The most important part in my case is the **Driver driver** attribute of the **RoadList class**

One function of the system is to make a monthly report for a **specific driver** and display the daily results in a table.

So I query from the database, selecting the month and driver. Then I populate the results in a List containing RoadList objects because the RoadList class maps the table in the database.

Using this design pattern I get a list with object where the attribute Driver is always the same because the report is for a specific driver only.

**Is there a more intelligent way to represent the data without having the repeating driver attribute?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your code, but if you're using an ORM framework such as Hibernate, the driver fields of all your beans would point to the same Driver object.  So you would have many references, but a single object.

If you're rolling your own, try creating a Driver object, and reusing it amongst your beans.